# Matching the distribution of a modeled data set to that of an observed data set?

Tags: r

I have two data sets. Let's assume they look like this for simplicity:

```
observed <- data.frame(name = c("Jenny", "Mark", "James", "Amber", "Jamie"),
                   height = c(68, 69, 72, 63, 77), 
                   mood = c("content", "content", "melancholy", "happy", "melancholy"))
modeled <- data.frame(name = c("Alex", "Jimmy", "Sal", "Evelyn", "Maria", "George", "Hilary", "Donny", "Jose", "Luke", "Leia"),
                  height = c(74, 71, 68, 66, 80, 59, 67, 67, 69, 65, 72), 
                  mood = c("content", "content", "melancholy", "happy", "melancholy","content", "content", "melancholy", "happy", "melancholy", "happy"))
```

I'd like to select rows from modeled such that that the distribution of modeled$heights is as close as possible to the distribution of observed$heights. I need to keep the rows intact rather than simply matching the distribution of the height integers. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *as close as possible*? If you filter `modeled` based on `modeled$height %in% observed$height`, then you would get exact matches. Is this what you want?

Comment: These are poor data sets to address the question because they're so small. I want the density distributions of the height columns to match.

Answer (score 1):

This is very ad hoc and there's surely better ways, but here's one:

```
my_sample <- dplyr::sample_n(modeled, nrow(observed))
```

Here's what they look like before we do anything:

```
plot(density(observed$height))
lines(density(my_sample$height), col = "red")
```

[image]

Then we pick a more similar sample:

```
while(cor(observed$height, my_sample$height) < .99){
  my_sample <- dplyr::sample_n(modeled, nrow(observed))
}
```

Then here's what it looks like after:

```
plot(density(observed$height))
lines(density(my_sample$height), col = "red")
```

[image]

With bigger data sets they should be even more similar, ceteris paribus.

You could even take it a little further (or at least try to, and see if there's enough variation in the modeling data to pull this off):

```
while(cor(observed$height, my_sample$height) < .99 | 
      abs(mean(observed$height) - mean(my_sample$height)) > .5){
  my_sample <- dplyr::sample_n(modeled, nrow(observed))
}
```

Now, one problem you might run into is if the modeling sample you want has to have more rows than the original data set. One way around that would be to use the mean and/or other summary statistics which don't require the sample length. Another way would be to use a sample of your sample, or to take multiple correlations of from chunks of your modeling data set.